# Are memory leaks somehow worse in windows than in linux?

Tags: memory-leaks

I randomly stumbled upon *The Art of C++, Chapter 2* while typing questions into google. I read this passage on memory leaks:

"Memory leaks cannot occur in a garbage collection environment because the garbage collector ensures that unused objects are eventually freed.
Memory leaks are a particularly troublesome problem in Windows programming, where the
failure to release unused resources slowly degrades performance."

Why is the author emphasizing Windows programming here as opposed to linux or OS X?

Are memory leaks somehow worse in windows than on linux?

Comment: Keep in mind this book is from the age of Windows XP. | With Windows GUI apps, it isn't just memory you can leak, there are GUI related resources like fonts, pens, brushes, etc. which were quite limited (as in thousands), more so in the older versions, where I have a feeling there wasn't even a per-process limit. Those could often be used on every redraw, so even a single leak there could quickly exhaust all available, and since they were global, it would hurt everything else running.